# Why my requests.post is not reading payload data?

Tags: python, api, python-requests

```
import requests
import json
payload = {'L1': '25', 'L2': '2050'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/',data=json.dumps(payload))
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

Here's the server code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def home(): 
    if(request.method == 'POST'): 

        data = "Level"
        return jsonify({'data': data})

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    app.run(debug = True)
```

Now I have to concatenate L1 and L2 values inside the flask service. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: The code works as it is written. You create a dict `{'data':'Level'}` and return it to the caller. What are you expecting to get?

Comment: I want to get: `{'L1': '25', 'L2': '2050'}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of inferring what you want, but you seem to have two problems. In the first part, you don't need the json.dumps, requests will do that for you. It will work better like this:

```
import requests
payload = {'L1': '25', 'L2': '2050'}
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/',data=payload)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code)
```

In part two, I imagine you got to this state trying to debug part one, you aren't dumping the value of the submitted form, but just the string "Level1", try this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST'])
def home(): 
    if(request.method == 'POST'): 

        data = request.form
        return jsonify(data)

if __name__ == '__main__': 

    app.run(debug = True)
```

Is that closer to what you are aiming at?

(Edited to reflect what you said in comment above about desired output. Works for me in Python 3.8.5)

Comment: I am not getting any output this way.

Comment: What version of python/requests/flask are you on?

Comment: Hrm, well, much less certain then. I just cut and pasted that code verbatim, and it gets the output you want.

>>> r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/',data=payload)
>>> print(r.text)
{
  "L1": "25", 
  "L2": "2050"
}

Comment: Now I have to concatenate L1 and L2 values inside the flask service. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: You just need to concatenate two values from a dictionary. I'm really not comfortable giving you more than that, sorry. This feels way too much like you're asking people to do homework for you line by line.